# How to find the combined variable with sub variables?

Tags: r, spss

I asked many questions to the Respondents. Each question represent a variable and they are part of the main variable. Each question has two possible answers : `Agree` and `Disagree` which I have coded to `1` and `0` respectively. It is like following:

```
Vraiables:
tax_revenue_a
tax_revenue_b
tax_revenue_c
non_tax_revenue_a
non_tax_revenue_b
non_tax_revenue_c
```

I need to combine the result to main variable like `tax_revenue` and `non_tax_revenue` and use it in cross tabulation.

Can I simply sum up the variables and use it like following? or Can I get the average of the sub-variables as the combined variables?

```
Sum:
  tax_revenue_sum = tax_revenue_a + tax_revenue_b + tax_revenue_c
  non_tax_revenue_sum = non_tax_revenue_a + non_tax_revenue_b + non_tax_revenue_c
Average:
  tax_revenue_avg = (tax_revenue_a + tax_revenue_b + tax_revenue_c) / 3
  non_tax_revenue_avg = (non_tax_revenue_a + non_tax_revenue_b + non_tax_revenue_c) /3
```

I have many more sub variables I have to use the result in cross-tabulation. If there are 3 sub-variables, we get value in range [0,3] if we sum up. If there are more than 3 sub-variables, there will be more levels and it is not very good to use in cross tabulation. I need to change this to dichotomous - `Agree`/`Disagree` variables.

Can the variable be broken at middle to get agree/disagree. For an example, if I have summed up 3 variables to get [0,3], then will recoding it as follows is okay or I need to try another method?

```
if combined variable is Sum of sub-variables:
  Any value less than 1.5 => 0 (Disagree) 
  Any value greater than 1.5 => 1 (Agree)
If combined variable is Average of sub-variables:
  Any value less than 0.5 => 0 (Disagree)
  Any value more than 0.5 => 1 (Agree)
```

How can it be done in better way? Is there any resource where I can find more about this?